# Make outbound call from asterisk width dynamic account

Tags: asterisk, sip, voip

I have asterisk on my server and I have a sip provider with very cheap rates.
for now I can only create sip account on the sip provider.

I want to have my customers create their account on my server and only after I allow them to pass call, my asterisk call the sip provider.

So the problem is when I want to make a call, I must provide dynamic username,domain,and password to the sip provider in the INVITE.

So I need to change the domain name in the from header and also if I receive the 401 error I must give the exact password so the call succeeds

How can we achieve that is asterisk?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you have described is a standard password challenge method. Asterisk has native support on that.

To enable it you will need to do the following on your sip.conf.

1. Set "defaultuser" and "secret" for your sip trunk
2. Make sure to remove "insecure" because that tells asterisk to skip password challenge.
3. See example below. You might need to adjust some configs to suit your need.

SIP trunk is always static, you can create multiple trunks and have your asterisk to pick one dynamically for a call.

```html
[sip_provider]
type=peer
defaultuser=<provider username>
secret=<provider secret>
host=<provider ip>
qualify=1000
qualifyfreq=600
context=from_endpoints
nat = force_rport,auto_comedia ; you might not need this
```